# Как создать такой скрол бар в drupal7?

Tags: drupal

Всем привет!

как создать такой скрол бар перелистывания в drupal7?

Надо связать с типом материала,то есть добавляешь фото,и оно там отображается?

может где то написано как такое реализовано?

очень жду вашей помощи)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

там материалы выводятся с нужными полями модулем views , а дальше , если выводится больше трех материалов , то с помощью Javascript  и  css  стилизуется вывод под слайдер (используя jquery ui slider) 
смотрите js и css  файлы - там все есть,
это называется ручная темизация вьюса

Comment: есть ссылки где это описано?

Comment: какие ссылки? Здесь нужно знание javascript  и  css
вот основная ссылка http://oooplastika.ru/sites/all/themes/base/js/script.js